# Getting "there was the package parsing error" on apk installation on Samsung note 8

Tags: android

When I am trying to install application on note 8 I'm getting this error. I am unable to install apk.

Comment: are you trying to run your own project or trying to install some other apk?

Comment: I am running my own project

Comment: Are you targetting the right api version? Try clean -> Rebuild and invalidate cache & restart

Comment: I am trying to  installing apk on note 8

Comment: Yes I am targeting right API version 27 and minimum 14

Comment: I tried all these solution but did not work. Any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem

> Rebuild the project and Build the apk again

you need to turn off Instant Run, go to

> File → Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run and
>   uncheck Enable Instant Run

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing the same issue even after Rebuild the project and apk again, then follow this,

1. Delete previously generated apk and json file in a Build folder.
2. Rebuild the project and generate apk again

(While rebuilding the project android studio delete the generated apk automatically )